# View Controller in IOS Programming

Tags: ios, segue, viewcontroller, splash-screen

Hey I have just started learning IOS Development and just got stuck in the part where we need to move on from one view controller to another dynamically. 
How to move from one view controller to another after a certain amount of time like splash screen in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [an explanation](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/using-nstimer-class-in-ios) of the magic of timing timey things in iOS.

> The NSTimer class can be used to create timer objects in iOS applications. In other words – a timer.

For triggering the segue, refer to [instructions here](https://prateekvjoshi.com/2013/11/02/how-to-trigger-a-segue-programmatically-in-ios/).

Comment: @RahilGoel If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.